# Drupal 7: Views RSS module - fields not showing up

Tags: views, feeds

So I wanted to create a custom RSS feed for my site and was told that I could use the views fields capability with this module: Views RSS. I downloaded and installed and followed the steps explained [here](http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/your-guide-to-extending-rss-feeds-in-drupal/) for the basic usage. And also took a look at the minimal instructions given at the module's doc

The problem is I end up with; the fields getting picked up by the page display but the feed display returns the default with title and body fields only (regardless of other fields). Also the XML is not outputted correctly and the link. It's as if the Views RSS is not there or is not doing anything.

I have no idea why it is not working...I am think if the steps I followed aren't correct and when I try to follow what is described [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1902026) I run into the same error and have no idea how the person who posted that solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First think first: On a RSS feed you can't have as many `<xml_tags>` as you want. It's fixed-predefined for web concurrency.

Now a quick and dirty tutorial:

1. Enable Views RSS, Views RSS: Core Elements, Views RSS: DC Elements
2. Add new view without create a page or a block
3. Add a Display Feed
4. Format-> from RSS Feed to RSS feed- Fields
5. Fields->Add the basic fields (It will display nothing!)
6. Format->Settings->Item elements : core Map the fields to RSS elements (do the same for Item elements : dc)
7. Feed settings->Path: give a path
8. Save..
9. Browse the URL, for debug (and not fancy Chrome/Firefox styling) `CURL example.com/rss`

Comment: Thanks for your reply tvl, followed the steps the xml code is outputted with the correct fields (but nothing displays on firefox). I previously solved the issue by adding a new view mode in my content types called "RSS" and in the default RSS view -> "Feed Display" -> Format-> content -> show -> display type "RSS", and the rss xml also outputted the fields that were setup in the "RSS" view mode, although apparently without a need for the Views RSS module.